# Sketching App for Android

Tags: android

I want a sketching app for android because I like to make sketches.

The App **must**…

1. run on Android 4.3.1
2. run on 256 MB RAM out of which, only 100MB is free.
3. must have an option to save as JPEG or GIF
4. must have different Brush and Colour Modes like in MS-Paint in Windows 7

I searched on SlideMe app market but, I found no good results.

Answer (score 2):

The app which I use with my Android Tablet is on the Google Play Store and it is called: Sketch Guru - Handy Sketch Pad. The application supports auto-saving every 2 minutes and it even recovers what you done last if the application crashes.

As for the RAM, I am not too totally sure how much it uses. I can say it does perform quite well without a second thought for myself. Also it is easy to pick up and use.